# variable_scope causes 'variable does not exist' with Optimizer

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, autoencoder

Supoose I have two models `foo` and `bar`. Assume `bar` is pretrained and loaded. I want to define the cost function for `foo` as roughly sketched in the following code (it's actually an autoencoder). Please note that this is an minimal example to reproduce my problem so they don't make sense mathematically.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def foo(X):
        with tf.variable_scope("foo"):
                A = tf.get_variable("A",shape=[1])
        return tf.add(X,A)

def bar(X):
        with tf.variable_scope("bar"):
                B = tf.get_variable("B",shape=[1])
        return tf.multiply(X,B)

X = tf.placeholder("float")

X_prime = foo(X)

Y = bar(X)
tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
Y_prime = bar(X_prime)


#foo(X) is manipulated with some other terms, but the point is foo is called again
cost = foo(X) + tf.pow(Y-Y_prime,2) 

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01).minimize(cost)
```

If I run the script (TF version 1.0), I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Variable foo/A/Adam/ does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=None in VarScope?
```

However, this doesn't happen with `GradientDescentOptimizer`. Any explanation and pointer would be appreciated.

Comment: Can someone help?

Comment: Have you solved your problem? In my opinion, after you set globally ``tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()``, all variables after that line will look for the existing variables. If there is no such variable, tensorflow will prompt that error. Optimizers like Momentum, Adam, they need to create variables to store the historical gradients when they try to ``minimize`` the cost. A possible way to solve this is that you can set  ``variable_scope("foo", reuse=reuse)`` locally by adding a parameter for the functions, not globally.

Answer (score 0):

Your ValueError is caused by creating new variables within the variable_scope.reuse==True.

Variables are created by Adam, when you call the minimize function of Adam, for saving momentums of each trainable variables in your graph.

You have set reuse to True, thus the default variable_scope.reuse==True. The reuse state cannot change back to False forever once you set it to True. Then, Adam creates variable under state reuse==True, which raises an error.

The solution is to add a sub scope under the graph's default scope when you set variable_scope.reuse=True, then the default scope.reuse is still False, and Adam.minimize will work, as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
def foo(X):
        with tf.variable_scope("foo"):
                A = tf.get_variable("A",shape=[1])
        return tf.add(X,A)

def bar(X):
        with tf.variable_scope("bar"):
                B = tf.get_variable("B",shape=[1])
        return tf.multiply(X,B)

X = tf.placeholder("float")

with tf.variable_scope("for_reuse_scope"):
    X_prime = foo(X)
    Y = bar(X)
    tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
    Y_prime = bar(X_prime)


#foo(X) is manipulated with some other terms, but the point is foo is called again
cost = foo(X) + tf.pow(Y-Y_prime,2) 

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01).minimize(cost)
```

Comment: You need to put:
with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope())
in front of the loop which runs over your devices ...

so, do that:

with tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope()):
    for i in xrange(FLAGS.num_gpus):
        with tf.device('/gpu:%d' % i):